# Restore DIfferential backup on azure managed instance?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am migrating my database from on-premise to Azure managed instance. In order to move the database I'm using the organization weekly full backup, and I am asking them to take a diff after they take the application offline (the databases are very large).

Question: Can I restore a differential backup on azure managed instance?

When I try to restore the full with norecovery than apply the DIFF. I get an error: "restore with norecovery is not a supported option in azure managed instance"

Answer (score 5):

> Question: Can I restore a differential backup on azure managed instance?

No. Borrowing from [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237036/1186), Managed Instance only supports the restore of full backups; no log or diff. See this thread:

- [Lesson Learned #82: Azure SQL Database Managed Instance supports only COPY_ONLY restoring a database backup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2019/03/22/lesson-learned-82-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-supports-only-copy_only-restoring-a-database-backup/)

And the limited syntax diagram for `RESTORE` in the documentation for Managed Instance:

- [RESTORE Statements (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current)

The docs imply that `RESTORE ... FROM URL` will implicitly add `WITH RECOVERY` and so there will be no opportunity for logs or diffs to be applied after the initial restore. So your downtime will be >= the time it takes to take a COPY_ONLY full backup, put it somewhere MI can access, restore it, and re-point your app(s). You might also want to read through [this tutorial, for a different approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-managed-instance#create-an-azure-database-migration-service-instance).

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Database Migration Assistant supports [online migration from SQL Server to Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-managed-instance-online).  But not all the underlying backup/restore functionality to do this is publicly available (currently).

Comment: I believe that DMS also does not support differential backups, but only full and then logs.

Comment: I believe so, but even the RESTORE LOG is not available for you to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring differential backups is now possible using
[Log Replay Service (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/log-replay-service-migrate).